# Adding, removing, and changing user names and passwords in .htpasswd with PHP

Tags: php, file-system, crud, .htaccess

Here is some code I wrote to add, remove, and change user names and passwords in .htpasswd with PHP:

```
function adduser($user, $pass) {

    try {

        $htpasswd = '.htpasswd';

        //$hash = '{SHA}'.crypt($pass, base64_encode($pass));

        $hash = crypt_apr1_md5($pass); //APR1-MD5

        $contents = $user . ':' . $hash;

        $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents($htpasswd)); // get .htpasswd

        print('<h4>input:</h4><pre>'.print_r(implode(PHP_EOL, $lines),true).'</pre>');

        $exists = false;

        foreach($lines as $line){

            $existing_user = explode( ':', $line );

            if ($existing_user[0] == $user) { //checks if user exists

                $contents = str_replace($line, $contents, $lines); //changes password for user

                $contents = implode(PHP_EOL, $contents);

                $exists = true;

                if ($pass == '') { // removes user if password is empty

                    $contents = str_replace($line, '', $lines); //removes user

                    $contents = array_filter($contents); // cleans empty space in array

                    $contents = implode(PHP_EOL, $contents);

                    $exists = true;

                }

            }

        }


        if ($exists == false) {

            $contents = implode(PHP_EOL, $lines) . PHP_EOL . $contents;
        }

        file_put_contents($htpasswd, $contents);

        print('<h4>output:</h4><pre>'.print_r($contents,true).'</pre>');

    }catch(Exception $e) {

        echo '<h3>fail: </h3>' . $e->getMessage();
    
    }

}

if(isset($_GET['user'])){

    adduser($_GET['user'], $_GET['pass']);

    echo '<h3>success</h3>';

}else{

    $htpasswd = '.htpasswd';

    $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents($htpasswd)); // get .htpasswd

    print('<h4>.htpasswd:</h4><pre>'.print_r(implode(PHP_EOL, $lines),true).'</pre>');

    echo '<h3>no user set</h3>';
}
```

I would love to streamline it and clean it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my version based on two personal preferences: I hate scroll bars and I hate repititions. Hence I prefer everything typed once and also I like my code being fully visible in the default code area on Stack Overflow.

- for this reason I removed that double spacing which just hurts my eyes
- also I removed the try catch which is a cargo cult code that makes no sense. I was never able to understand what's the point in writing a try catch that's the only job is to echo the error message when without a try catch PHP will do exactly the same - echo the error message
- also I removed the code repetitions such as mentioning the filename in a dozen places
- also I changed the algorithm, to make it add a user line only once
- I also removed that uncertainty when we can't make our mind whether we are working with an array or with a text
- I also changed the function name as it doesn't only add a user
- and some other improvements such as following the HTTP guidelines and the ability to choose the hashing algorithm without using inline comments

here it goes

```
<?php
$filename = ".htpasswd";
if (isset($_POST['user'])) {
    manage_htpasswd($_POST['user'], $_POST['pass'], $filename);
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit;
}
function manage_htpasswd($user, $pass, $filename, $algo = 'crypt_apr1_md5')
{
    $lines = file($filename);
    foreach ($lines as $i => $line) {
        $existing_user = explode(':', $line);
        if ($existing_user[0] === $user) {
            unset($lines[$i]);
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($pass) {
        $lines[] = "$user:" . $algo($pass) . PHP_EOL;
    }
    file_put_contents($filename, $lines);
}
?>
<form method="post">
    User: <input type="text" name="user"><br>
    Pass:<input type="text" name="pass"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<h4><?= $filename ?>:</h4>
<pre>
<?= file_get_contents($filename) ?>
</pre>
```

Comment: So instead of updating a row, you delete it then append it to the end of the file.  Fair enough.

Comment: @mickmackusa yeah I was thinking how to get rid of that found/not found business :)

Comment: I think I like your non-regex versus my regex technique.  Perhaps use `strstr()` with a `true` param instead of exploding to create `$existing_user` from an array (this way you don't even need to declare the variable).  Your snippet is still making iterated function calls, but it does return early -- looks pretty clean to me and built with flexibility in mind.

Comment: $lines[] = "$user:" . $algo($pass); doesn't create a new line. It needs to be: $lines[] = "$user:" . $algo($pass) . PHP_EOL; no?

Comment: @tony surely it does. Like I said, we need to move from that uncertainty, whether we are working with array or text. In favor of arrays. And [] in terms of arrays is exactly that: a new line

Comment: @YourCommonSense - it's not creating a new line on my end when I use it.

Comment: @tony but how does it look? what new line you are talking about? An empty line after the new line? but why would you need that empty line? Your PHP_EOL adds an **empty** line *after* the new line with a user.

Comment: @YourCommonSense - https://imgur.com/a/xSnqL8C user1, 2, 3 were added using my code, newuser4, 5, 6 were added using your code. It is not possible to remove them this way either. Adding . PHP_EOL; fixes this problem, but as you said, we want to get away from that.

Comment: @tony wait. indeed it does that. let me check

Comment: @tony I beg my pardon. yes, my bad. there must be a PHP_EOL. So, when we are moving from a text to an array, every line in this array holds a new line symbol. when file_put_contents converts an array back to text, it just glues all the lines together. if a line holds a new line symbol, then the next one occurs on the new line. But once the line doesn't have a new line at the end, then the next line is glued to it. So every line should have a new line at the end. Means we have to add it to the new line.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of your code and mine, I hope that the usernames cannot contain any colons since that is the delimiting character between usernames and passwords!

I have a bias toward regex because I have a fair handle on it and I enjoy the utility and brevity that it affords my scripts.  I also don't (personally) enjoy all of the imploding and exploding going on in your script.

The search pattern is the same for cases of deleting and updating -- only the replacement text is changed.  My search pattern will look for an **optional** leading newline character/sequence with `\R`, then search for an identical match of the username followed by a colon, then match the remainder of the line of text.  This line-consuming pattern means that if replacing with an empty string, then there will be no blank line in the file; alternatively, if updating, then a leading EOL character/sequence will be prepended (don't worry, I `ltrim()` later).

The single `preg_replace()` call will record the number of replacements that it makes.  The number will be either 0 or 1 since the fourth parameter limits the replacements to 1 anyhow.  If there were no replacements made, then logically we know that a new line is to be appended to the end of the file.

At the end of the custom function, I am going the extra step of returning the action that was successfully undertaken.  The will give better information in the output.

`isset()` can receive multiple arguments, so I added the pass element as well since it is expected with the submission.

I am using `printf()` to output the mix of literal and dynamic text -- I find that it helps to make the code more readable.

Untested Code:

```
function editHtpasswordRow(string $user, string $pass): string
{
    $file = '.htpasswd';
    if ($pass === '') {
        $newRow = '';
        $action = 'Delete';
    } else {
        $newRow = PHP_EOL . $user . ':' . crypt_apr1_md5($pass);
        $action = 'Update';
    }

    $content = preg_replace(
        '/\R?^' . preg_quote($user, '/') . ':.*/mu',
        $newRow,
        file_get_contents($file),
        1,
        $count
    );

    if (!$count && $newRow) {
        $content .= PHP_EOL . $newRow;
        $action = 'Insert';
    }
    file_put_contents($file, ltrim($content));
    return $action;
}

if (isset($_POST['user'], $_POST['pass'])) {
    printf(
        '<h3>%s of %s was successful</h3>',
        editHtpasswordRow($_POST['user'], $_POST['pass']), 
        htmlspecialchars($_POST['user'])
    );
} else {
    echo '<h4>Fetched .htpasswd content:</h4><pre>' . file_get_contents('.htpasswd') . '</pre>';
}
```

---

Edit: I missed something that YourCommonSense spotted... You should be using `$_POST` when writing to the filesystem.  `$_GET` is for reading and `$_POST` is for writing.  I'll update my snippet now, +1 his post, and advise you to use his html form.